# Extract Text from HTTP referer

Tags: php, wordpress, http-referer

I am using the following code to show the referer link any page on my website. How can i modify the code so that it only shows part of the link. i.e if my website url is www.example.com/?s=printing i only want it to extract printing. And this should only happen if the format is www.example.com/?s=aaa and not if the format is anything else like www.example.com/printing.

Code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) )
$_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
echo $_SESSION["origURL"] 
?>
```

Comment: Why not just check for `$_GET['s']`?

Comment: @RST how would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and the following code works:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) )
    $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
    $mysearchterm = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
    $whatIWant = substr($mysearchterm, strpos($mysearchterm, "=") +1);    
    echo  $whatIWant;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Values that are send to a page as part of a link are stored by default in the `$_GET` variable. Your URL is using `s=printing`. This means the name of the property is `s` and the value of the property is `printing`

Instead of all the string search actions you could use

```
if ( isset($_GET['s']) ) $whatIWant = $_GET['s'];
```