# Only use http refer if from certain page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-referer

I am using the following code to display a string from a url and it works fine. However, I only want to use this code if the initial refering page is my search page:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) )
    $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
    $mysearchterm = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
    $whatIWant = substr($mysearchterm, strpos($mysearchterm, "=") +1);    

    echo  $whatIWant;
    ?>
```

Comment: You posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035882/extract-text-from-http-referer and that is the exact copy of the answer you gave http://stackoverflow.com/a/35037440/ - so, you'd technically have to answer that answer of your answer, yourself ;-)

Comment: You shouldn't rely on on `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` btw. It's not reliable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the question is different because i want to know how to use this code for only the search page. Why shoulndn't i rely on this `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` and what could be a work around?

Comment: If you control the previous page, you can pass the URL as a parameter `"http://example.com/page2.php?prevUrl=".urlencode("http://example.com/page1.php")`. If you don't control the page, then there is nothing you can do.